# Trying to Implement Linear Regression with Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, stochastic, logistics

[[Dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AVNrWBwn22c1QWc6X9zG8FkvTMXHXZGuZH2sPAT9a00/edit?usp=sharing)][1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AVNrWBwn22c1QWc6X9zG8FkvTMXHXZGuZH2sPAT9a00/edit?usp=sharing)I'm attempting to implement linear regression for stochastic gradient descent using python. I have the code to enable me do this but for some reason, its triggering an error at "row[column] = float(row[column].strip())"-could not convert string to float: 'C'". Anyone who will assist me troubleshoot this error will be greatly appreciated.

```
  # Linear Regression With Stochastic Gradient Descent for Pima- Indians-Diabetes

  from random import seed
  from random import randrange
  from csv import reader
  from math import sqrt
  filename = 'C:/Users/Vince/Desktop/University of Wyoming PHD/Year 2/Machine 
  Learning/Homeworks/Solutions/HW4/pima-indians-diabetes-training.csv'
  # Load a CSV file
  def load_csv(filename):
  dataset = list()
  with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = reader(filename)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if not row:
            continue
        dataset.append(row)
   return dataset

  # Convert string column to float
  def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
  for row in dataset:
    row[column] = float(row[column].strip())

  # Find the min and max values for each column
  def dataset_minmax(dataset):
  minmax = list()
  for i in range(len(dataset[0])):
    col_values = [row[i] for row in dataset]
    value_min = min(col_values)
    value_max = max(col_values)
    minmax.append([value_min, value_max])
  return minmax

  # Rescale dataset columns to the range 0-1
  def normalize_dataset(dataset, minmax):
    for row in dataset:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        row[i] = (row[i] - minmax[i][0]) / (minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0])

  # Split a dataset into k folds
  def cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds):
  dataset_split = list()
  dataset_copy = list(dataset)
  fold_size = int(len(dataset) / n_folds)
  for i in range(n_folds):
    fold = list()
    while len(fold) < fold_size:
        index = randrange(len(dataset_copy))
        fold.append(dataset_copy.pop(index))
    dataset_split.append(fold)
 return dataset_split

# Calculate root mean squared error
def rmse_metric(actual, predicted):
sum_error = 0.0
for i in range(len(actual)):
    prediction_error = predicted[i] - actual[i]
    sum_error += (prediction_error ** 2)
mean_error = sum_error / float(len(actual))
return sqrt(mean_error)

# Evaluate an algorithm using a cross validation split
def evaluate_algorithm(dataset, algorithm, n_folds, *args):
folds = cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds)
scores = list()
for fold in folds:
    train_set = list(folds)
    train_set.remove(fold)
    train_set = sum(train_set, [])
    test_set = list()
    for row in fold:
        row_copy = list(row)
        test_set.append(row_copy)
        row_copy[-1] = None
    predicted = algorithm(train_set, test_set, *args)
    actual = [row[-1] for row in fold]
    rmse = rmse_metric(actual, predicted)
    scores.append(rmse)
return scores

# Make a prediction with coefficients
def predict(row, coefficients):
yhat = coefficients[0]
for i in range(len(row)-1):
    yhat += coefficients[i + 1] * row[i]
return yhat

# Estimate linear regression coefficients using stochastic gradient descent
def coefficients_sgd(train, l_rate, n_epoch):
coef = [0.0 for i in range(len(train[0]))]
for epoch in range(n_epoch):
    for row in train:
        yhat = predict(row, coef)
        error = yhat - row[-1]
        coef[0] = coef[0] - l_rate * error
        for i in range(len(row)-1):
            coef[i + 1] = coef[i + 1] - l_rate * error * row[i]
        # print(l_rate, n_epoch, error)
   return coef

   # Linear Regression Algorithm With Stochastic Gradient Descent
  def linear_regression_sgd(train, test, l_rate, n_epoch):
  predictions = list()
  coef = coefficients_sgd(train, l_rate, n_epoch)
  for row in test:
    yhat = predict(row, coef)
    predictions.append(yhat)
 return(predictions)

 # Linear Regression on Indians Pima Database
  seed(1)
# load and prepare data
filename = 'C:/Users/Vince/Desktop/University of Wyoming PHD/Year 2/Machine 
Learning/Homeworks/Solutions/HW4/pima-indians-diabetes-training.csv'
dataset = load_csv(filename)
for i in range(len(dataset[0])):
str_column_to_float(dataset, i)
# normalize
minmax = dataset_minmax(dataset)
normalize_dataset(dataset, minmax)
# evaluate algorithm
n_folds = 5
l_rate = 0.01
n_epoch = 5 0
scores = evaluate_algorithm(dataset, linear_regression_sgd, n_folds, l_rate, n_epoch)
print('Scores: %s' % scores)
print('Mean RMSE: %.3f' % (sum(scores)/float(len(scores))))
```

Comment: Can you share the error that it is throwing?

Comment: At the line `def load_csv('C:/Users/Vince/Desktop/University of Wyoming PHD/Year 2/Machine Learning/Homeworks/Solutions/HW4/pima-indians-diabetes-training.csv'):` you cannot have string as an argument when defining a function. It has to be a variable name or variable name with a default value.

Comment: @ranka47, thank you. I switched the argument for the function from a string to a variable and it worked. Now it's throwing a new error at row[column] = float(row[column].strip()) and str_column_to_float(dataset, i); "Value Error: could not convert string to float: 'C'"

Comment: Can you reflect the changes you made in the code here in the question? Also, can you edit the question to include the complete error that you are facing?

Comment: Also, can you add sample of the dataset/csv file? One of the column that you are trying to convert has character 'C' hence it is not able to convert to float.

Comment: @ranka47, I've reflected the code changes in the question and I've edited the question to include the complete error. I've also attached the dataset. Please let me know if there's anything else you need.

Comment: Please refer to this -> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  The dataset requires google account login.

Comment: @ranka47, I've edited the dataset so that you can now access it. Please click on the link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to the answer from @Agni

The CSV file that you are reading has a header line

`num_preg   PlGlcConc   BloodP  tricept insulin BMI ped_func    Age HasDiabetes`

When you use `reader(file)` to read the file and then iterate over it, the first line also gets added in `dataset`. Hence, the first element in `dataset` list is:

```
>>> dataset
[['num_preg', 'PlGlcConc', 'BloodP', 'tricept', 'insulin', 'BMI', 'ped_func', 'Age', 'HasDiabetes'], ...]
```

So when you try to convert it into float it throws the error,
`Could not convert string to float): numpreg`

Here is the final edited code:

```
def load_csv(filename):
    dataset = list()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        fieldnames = next(csv_reader) # Skip the first row and store in case you need it
        dataset = list(csv_reader) # You can convert an iterator to list directly
    return dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

In function load_csv, you are using `with open(filename, 'r') as file:`
But in the next line instead of passing the file object `file` you pass the reader the string `filename`, and your dataset is created using this `filename` string, therefore when you end up trying to convert the letter 'C' to float.
Just change the line `reader(filename)` to `reader(file)`
That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually just tried that but it triggered the same error. This time I think the error was associated with the dataset; specifically the numpreg column.

"Could not convert string to float): numpreg. I'll modify the question to include the dataset."

Comment: The first line of your dataset contains column names, but your code does not make provisions to capture that separately.  Instead, it starts trying to read data in float format. put like this before you start reading data.` columns = dataset[0]` before you start the data parsing loop and also begin the loop from index 1 not 0 as index 0 contains column names.

Comment: Also please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you, thank you!